# date format giving error in server in local working fine in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, date, iis-7, excel-import

I have a functionality which upload an excel sheet to database. 
One of the validation is checking then date format given in excel sheet is dd/MM/yyyy

for that i do a regular expression check as below

```
if (!checkRegex(member["DOB"].ToString().Trim()))
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("DOBFORMAT", "Date of Birth is not in dd/MM/YYYY for record " + count + ". Please check");
System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
return View();
}
```

and regulare expression checking function is

```
      public bool checkRegex(string inputstring)
                {
            DateTime date;
           string format;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)
    (?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))
    (?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3
    (?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|
    (?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$");
 try
{
 date = Convert.ToDateTime(inputstring);
 format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 string check = date.ToString(format);
 if (regex.IsMatch(check))
     return true;
else
     return false;
   }


     catch
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
        }
```

when I am uploading an excel sheet with `"27/08/1983"` from `server` it is giving error that date format is wrong for the record.

I tried the same with `localhost` and done debugging. It passed the regular expression and uploaded successfully.

Date format in `server` and `localhost` is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Also other excel sheets are uploading successfully.

Please show some light on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when you try to create a datetime object from the string, Your code crashes in this line.

```
date = Convert.ToDateTime(inputstring);
```

If you know your date string will be always in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you may use the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method to build a datetime object from a string.

```
DateTime parsedDate;

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(inputstring,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                     DateTimeStyles.None,out parsedDate))
{
    // parsedDate is a valid DateTime object now
    // return true;
}
else
{
    // could not create a valid DateTime object from inputString
    // return false;
}
```